# What is the best way to implement a Dynamic Web Page which will be used as a WebView?

Tags: javascript, performance, webview

I wanted to create a new web application which utilizes a lot of data from backend. This should be used as a WebView. I started my work using normal javascript. Everything is working fine but during the development of my page I am doubtful about the approach that I am following. Is it a good idea to use normal JavaScript to fetch a lot of data from backend or else is there any better alternative to do this.

Will the approach that I am following effects the app performance later?

Comment: JavaScript isn't slow, and even if it were, it isn't fetching the data. The browser does that, and the bottleneck is the speed of the internet connection. If you still have doubts about this, why not stress test your approach right now?

Comment: Thank you for your advice @ChrisG. My work is in progress and once done i will stress test it. Thanks again